# Source not found in class file editor

Tags: android, eclipse

My eclipse is not showing description of any default classes.
It is showing:
*Source not found.*

The source attachment does not contain the source for the file `GestureDetector.class`

You can change the source attachment by clicking change attached source below

Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

As the error say. Click on "Change attached source" (there should be a button) and specify the jar file or folder that does contain the source code for this class.

I assume, that you include some jar file that contains `GestureDetector.class` in your project. Per default, Eclipse looks into this jar for the source code. Thus, I assume the jar contains binary only. Thus, you need to get a different jar that contains binaries and source code. Or you need to download the source code from somewhere on the Internet (if available), store in at any location you like and then specify this folder as indicated at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach the java documentation and if you already have, navigate to the folder and select it.  If you dont have you either download or make. To make download Jdecompiler it will generate the source for you.
You can also take help of grepcode [here](http://grepcode.com/)